# Dielectrics and polarization

Tags: polarization, dielectric

What do we refer to when we say that a dielectric is statically polarized? How can we obtain such a state? (I've been searching on the web, but haven't found too much)
Thanks!

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret

Comment: Apply a static electric field. The positive and negative charges will undergo relative displacements at the microscopic level. It gives rise to a tiny dipoles which constitutes bound charges inside V and on the surface S of the dielectric.

Answer (score 1):

Dielectric means that the molecules of the material are polar ones (the charge is not homogeneously distributed). Normally the poles of the molecules have not a particular orientation, but, when that molecules are near an electric field, the material is polarized because all positive poles are pointing to a particular direction (and negative to the opposite direction).